# Copy an image and rename it to match other file names

Tags: image, file, batch-file, copy, rename

I have ZERO bat knowledge so thought I would ask here, if I may.

I have an image `C:\Users\Dane\Pictures\Doom.jpg`. I wish for this image to be copied and for it to be renamed to the exact name of *379 non-image* type files which are in another folder which is `G:\Doom`. So I will have the same image *379 times* but named to match the *379 files*.

Would anyone be kind enough to write a bat file to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a free code writing service, but a question and answer site for programming-related topics. Either try it on your own, and if stuck, come back here with a [mceve], or hire a programmer for the task! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is not a free code writing service; Rather give the subject an attempt and we will be happy to assist you. However, because I'm nice, I have a response for you.

This problem is pretty common and can be solved very easily using a `FOR` statement. In this example we will be searching a directory for every item stored inside. Each item will be added to the integer `%%A`. For more information do `FOR /?` inside a command window.

```
for %%a in ("Directory") DO (Action)
```

For copying files, we will use the `copy` command. Please keep note that we will be using parameter extensions to expand the %%A to have no extension using `%%~na`. More info here: [Parameter Extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

This script will copy & rename `Doom.jpg` to `G:\Doom` for each item in the directory.

**Batch File:**

```
for %%a in ("G:\Doom\*") do (copy "C:\Users\Dane\Pictures\Doom.jpg" "G:\Doom\%%~na.png")
```

**Command Prompt:**

```
for %a in ("G:\Doom\*") do (copy "C:\Users\Dane\Pictures\Doom.jpg" "G:\Doom\%~na.png")
```

Comment: I did not know that about this site but will make sure I adhere to that in the future. Thank you very much for your help as that worked great.

Comment: @DaneAbomasum The least you can do for me is checking my response as solved if it resolved your issue. Right under the two arrows on the left.